# TYPO3 installtool just reloads when using correct password

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

i'm using TYPO3 7.6LTS behind loadBalancer and can not access InstallTool. No Errors shown in logs, the page is just reloading after entering the correct Password and asks for it again. I found many solutions for the "Installtool-page-Reload-Problem" but none is working out for me; those are mostly for TYPO3 4.3 / 4.5 or 6.2 and solved in higher versions.

Comment: Do you try to enter the Installtool directly by domain.com/typo3/install or inside the backend using the backend module to the install tool? I'm sometimes having problems with the BE compressionlevel configured in the LocalConfiguration.php which can cause problems with Backend Logins.

Comment: Hi, i tried both. inside the backend-tool and directly, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deactivate the Load Balancer and access the web server directly?

For a Load Balancer you need the reverse proxy configuration in TYPO3:

```
    'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'first',
    'reverseProxyIP' => '[IP of Load Balancer]',
    'reverseProxySSL' => '*',
```